# non blocking I/O in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My application build reports based on data gathered from external APIs what can take a few minutes. Naturally, I do not want to block the worker process. Is it possible to  send data gathering to the background and allow user to  work with application further?
Also it will be good to display the state of the job with SSE or WebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would dispatch a *background job* to **[Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)** or another background job queue, and have your worker perform jobs from the queue.

That looks like this:

```
class ReportGenerationJob
  # ...

  def work
    # do expensive operations here
  end
end

r = Resque.new
r << ReportGenerationJob.new(...)   # Not a blocking operation!
```

Once a given job is completed, your worker can then signal when it's done in some helpful way (e.g. e-mailing the user that the job is completed; writing a "done!" value to your database; et cetera).

Comment: but how do I send a WebSocket or SSE on job completion? Is there some kind of 'promise' or something available?I mean shouldn't I wait for it to be complete what will discredit the while resque stuff?

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to do that, and it will depend a lot on which kind of platform you're on and your other requirements. One article that might be helpful is here: http://www.bytelion.com/blog/rails-app-with-html5-websockets/